# Is there any App where I can show where I click on an non-jailbroken iPad?

Tags: mirroring

I am using a mirroring app to present to people in a different geographic location, and I need to show them where I am clicking using different Apps, I know that PPT and Keynote already have those capabilities, but we are using iBooks and other Apps (in-house developments)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to shell out $20, I believe Reflector can do it and it has nice graphics additions for screen recordings (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I have Reflector2 and updated to the latest release, the iPad and the Mac cannot connect (Mirroring360 can, but it does not have the "pointer" option)

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording this for future playback, I recommend [ScreenFlow](https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/). You can enable the setting for a visual indication of taps and clicks in the video, which makes it very easy to follow.

Edit: [Highlighter](http://customsolutionsofmaryland.50megs.com/highlighter.htm/) does what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, no, I need it for live presentations and meetings

Comment: @edoliver see my edit.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently Highlighter works only with OS X? I need it for iOS though (either way I am keeping it for my Mac)